# Could a non-algebraically closed PAC field be a finite extension of an ordered field?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields

Is there such an example? Or it is known that a pseudo algebraically closed field which is a finite extension of a formally real field is algebraically closed?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you can take your formally real field to be the field $\mathbb{Q}^{tr}$ of totally real algebraic numbers (see [this paper](http://www.math.uci.edu/~mfried/paplist-cov/QTotallyReal.pdf) for a description of its Galois group).  Then (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_algebraically_closed_field)), adjoining a square root of $-1$ gives you a pseudo algebraically closed field.